# toupper tolower

Tags: c, tolower, toupper

How to use topper and tolower in the C language?
I've tried to run the program that I've made, it runs properly
the problem is since I should submit it to a website to check it whether it's right or wrong, every time I submit it, it says compile error.

I made the code on macbook, using Xcode and it says on my toupper and tolower code -- implicit declaration of function 'toupper' is invalid in C99

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    int input;
    scanf("%d",&input);
    int jumlahkata;

    char kalimat[100];

    for(int i=0;i<input;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s",kalimat);
        jumlahkata=strlen(kalimat);
        for(int j=0;j<jumlahkata;j++)
        {
            if(j%2==0 || j==0)
            {
                kalimat[j]=toupper(kalimat[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                kalimat[j]=tolower(kalimat[j]);
            }
        }
        printf("%s\n",kalimat);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this `jumlahkata = strlen()` just `for (int j = 0 ; kalimat[j] != '\0' ; ++j)` is fine. Also, you can write readable pleasant to the eyes code. And to avoid this error enable compiler warnings, the compiler should tell you *implicit declaration of function `tolower()`*.

Comment: And `0 % 2` is also `0`.

Comment: You get a warning *locally* (the `implicit declaration`); chances are warnings are treated as errors on that website where you are submitting it to. So get rid of these warnings. Reading [about any random manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tolower) should be enough.

Comment: Do you know the compiler and version used by the website you submit to? To be safe, `#include <ctype.h>` and move all your five variable declarations to the top of the `main()` function, including those in `(for int i...)` and `(for int j...)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`toupper` and `tolower` are defined in `ctype.h`. Simply include this file with the line `#include <ctype.h>`.

Comment: Has nothing to do with his problem. He says "it runs propely", hence it compiles

Comment: Sure, it *compiles* fine, but it *works* purely by chance. The compiler assumes a function taking an `int` and returning an `int`, which in this case just *happens* to be correct!

Answer (score 1):

You need to include header `<ctype.h>` .

Also `int jumlahkata;` should be of type `size_t` as you store result of `strlen` in it.

Or don't use it (as also pointed out by @iharob Sir ) , it unnecessary. As it is string , just check for `null character` as a condition in loop.

Comment: Or don't use `strlen()` at all. Because doing it means counting characters twice.

Comment: @iharob  Yes , that's unnecessary , he can just check for `'\0'` its a string after all .

Comment: Yes, he needs to include the header but it has nothing to do with his problem. He says "it runs propely", hence it compiles. He mixes C and C++ in a lenient environment.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  From C99 onwards we can declare variables as C++ . Therefore that is fine , I think he uses C99 as he uses `for` loop declaration also.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  Also compilation gives warning of implicit declaration . That's what problem is you see .

Comment: "From C99 onwards we can declare variables as C++ ." is unclear.  I find nothing in the C (C99,C11) spec specifying how to declare variables as C++.  Perhaps you meant in C++, variable can be declared as C.

Comment: @chux  Yeah ,it came out a bit confusing . But rather it was for declaring variable anywhere in function .

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing C with C++:

```
int input;
scanf("%d",&input);          // in C, following the first executable statement you may not declare variables until the next block
int jumlahkata;              // declaring the variable here is C++

char kalimat[100];           // declaring the variable here is C++

for(int i=0;i<input;i++)     // declaring the variable here is C++
```